Numbers reminding me of cities
I look at these numbers and they can be related to cities. Which? Why?
35108
1710
50337
Think creatively.

These three numbers relate (respectively) to:

 BOISE (the capital of Idaho, US), DILI (the capital of Timor-Leste) and LEEDS (in the UK).

Because...

 ...if you rotate these numbers by 180 degrees (and imagine them written on a 7-segment calculator display), the upside-down numbers somewhat resemble the city names spelled out!

 35108 -> BOISE
 1710 -> DILI
 50337 -> LEEDS

 i.e. 0=D, 1=I, 3=E, 5=S, 7=L, 8=B.

Diagrammatically:

 


Funny, I was following the same approach, but still missed the city names. Probably because I didn't know some of the cities.

0 looks like O and D
